# Testing rails engine helpers with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I've searched a bit but I can't find a good explanation about it so here is my question.

I'm writing a Rails engine that only adds helpers.

The structure is like this (the important part):

```
my_engine/
  -- app/
     -- helpers/
        -- my_engine/
           -- my_engine_helper.rb
  -- spec/
     -- dummy/
     -- spec_helper.rb
```

My `spec_helper.rb` is the following:

```ruby
# Configure Rails Envinronment
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] = 'test'
require File.expand_path('../dummy/config/environment.rb',  __FILE__)

require 'rspec/rails'

ENGINE_RAILS_ROOT = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '../')

# Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc,
# in spec/support/ and its subdirectories.
Dir[File.join(ENGINE_RAILS_ROOT, 'spec/support/**/*.rb')].each { |f| require f }

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
end
```

So far so good, but I'm not sure about how to test my helper.
I would like to know what is the best way to:

- organize the test files
- test that the dummy app can use the helper
- test the helper itself

For now I get the following error when running the spec:

```
undefined local variable or method `helper' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_1:0x007fcee8b0f4a0>
```

with the following test:

```ruby
require 'spec_helper'

module MyEngine
  describe MyEngineHelper do
    describe '#something' do
      it "does something" do
        helper.something.should be_true
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Thank you !

Comment: Where is the spec located relative to your spec directory?

Comment: Also, you can just do `require 'spec_helper'`.

Comment: Ok I updated the spec. I located the spec in spec/my_engine/my_engine_helper_spec.rb but I don't know if it's the right place.

Comment: You test the helper logic in spec and move the logic to lib later ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move it to `spec/helpers/my_engine_helper_spec.rb`. The `rspec-rails` has a hook for things in `spec/helpers` to add the `helper` method.

Answer (score 1):

I would check out how activeadmin does this

https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/blob/master/spec/unit/helpers/settings_spec.rb

This is a rails engine with a very high quality test suite (I contributed to it)